# Git not working w/ HTTPS method

Tags: git, github, homebrew

I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion using git version:

```
git version 1.7.11.3
```

I am following exactly what this tutorial says (except the part about the passwords) and keep getting an error when using the 'push' command.

Tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
Tutorial 2: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

When I type the final command on the 2nd page of the tutorial:

```
git push origin master
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: https://github.com/tabchas/Hello-World.git/info/refs not found: did you run git      update-server-info on the server?
```

I installed git via Homebrew if that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your GitHub account, I don't see a "Hello-World" repo.  You need to click "New Repository" in your account and add one named "Hello-World".

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't see that on the tutorial. Wow... nvm.